# Sort images based on order number using laravel

Tags: php, html, image, laravel, sorting

I have 5 images. I need to show the images based on the order.

Now I have the order in the array like

```
2,3,5,1,4
```

Now my images are in `$new->image1,$new->image2,$new->image3,$new->image4,$new->image5`

My result should be like if order is as like above,

order is like `$new->image2,$new->image3,$new->image5,$new->image5,$new->image1,$new->image4`

How can I achieve this

```
<table style="text-align:justify" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" >
     {{$new->img_order}}
     <?php 
      $order_array = explode(",", $new->img_order);
      $img1 = $new->image2;
      dd($new->image2);
     ?>
            <tr>
              <td height="600" rowspan="3"><img width="350" height="910px" src="{{asset('collage/'.$new->image1)}}" class="img-responsive" alt=""></td>
              <td height="300" colspan="2"><img width="500" height="300px" src="{{asset('collage/'.$new->image2)}}" class="img-responsive" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="250" ><img width="250" height="350px" src="{{asset('collage/'.$new->image3)}}" class="img-responsive" alt=""></td>
              <td width="250"><img width="250" height="350px" src="{{asset('collage/'.$new->image4)}}" class="img-responsive" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><img width="500" height="250px" src="{{asset('collage/'.$new->image5)}}" class="img-responsive" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: I just wonder why you not save the image path in array, but with many `image1, image2, ....`.

Comment: @KrisRoofe  i agreed with you.

Comment: @krisroofe., why path? we have the image name in DB and will retrieve like this na

Comment: @KavyaShree I just show a example above. I mean why not use a array to save each image, with with many indexes or properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wonder why you not save the image path in array, but with many `image1, image2, ....`.

Without sorting the image, you can echo the image by the order array with

```
$new->{'image' . $order[0]}
$new->{'image' . $order[1]}
$new->{'image' . $order[2]}
...
```